# Only sort the NA's at the end of a vector R

Tags: r, na

Is it possible to sort a vector where the order for non-missing/non-NA values is maintained, but the NA's in the vector are sorted to the end?

For example could I turn this vector

```
vector<-c("Dog", "Cat", NA, "Tiger", NA, "Bear")
```

into this

```
vector<-c("Dog","Cat","Tiger","Bear", NA, NA)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `NA` value using `na.omit` and subset till the length of vector to get `NA` at end.

```
na.omit(vector)[1:length(vector)]
#[1] "Dog"   "Cat"   "Tiger" "Bear"  NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `order` the vector using `factor` with appropriate `levels=`.

```
vector[order(factor(vector, levels=vector))]
# [1] "Dog"   "Cat"   "Tiger" "Bear"  NA      NA
```

Comment: Upvote, but perhaps worth adding to the answer that using it with duplicated strings will fail

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
sort(factor(vector, levels = vector), na.last = TRUE)

[1] Dog   Cat   Tiger Bear  <NA>  <NA>
```

If some strings could be duplicated:

```
sort(factor(vector, levels = unique(vector)), na.last = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also do:

```
vector[order(is.na(vector))]

# [1] "Dog"   "Cat"   "Tiger" "Bear"  NA      NA
```

`TRUE` (equals 1) is higher than `FALSE` (equals 0), so `NA`'s are moved to the end while all `TRUE` cases to the beginning, without taking into account the real strings.

Works as well with duplicated strings, for example:

```
vector <- c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat", NA, "Tiger", NA, "Bear")

vector[order(is.na(vector))]

# [1] "Dog"   "Dog"   "Cat"   "Tiger" "Bear"  NA      NA
```